# Get integer index values from DateTimeIndex in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

How can I get a range of underlying indices number from DataFrame with DateTimeIndex? Some rows are removed, so the values may not be sequential.

For example:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df
Out[3]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2000-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2000-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2000-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
2000-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
2000-01-06 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
2000-01-07  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
2000-01-08 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
```

For `df.index` I would like instead of

```
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03' ...], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

to get

```
[1, 2, 4, ...,26, etc]
```

Is this possible in a wat that does not include `df.reset_index()`?

Comment: are you thinking of using the date part of the index (01, 25, ..) and the max integer may not be greater than 31?

Comment: No. I am thinking of using the underlying integer index for DataFrame.

Comment: There is no underlying integer index. If you drop the DatetimeIndex, Pandas will default to a RangeIndex set to the number of rows in your DataFrame.

Answer (score 4):

To get this:

```
[1, 2, 4, ...,26, etc]
```

without using `df.reset_index()` (ie; leaving the `DatetimeIndex` as is), why don't you iterate on the *Range* of the *Length* of the index itself:

```
range(df.index.shape[0])
```

and to get a list directly you may use *List Comprehension*:

```
[i for i in range(df.index.shape[0])]
```

You might also want to check [`df.index.get_loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html), which returns the integer location of a specific requested index label.

```
unique_index = pd.Index(list('abc'))
unique_index.get_loc('b')

>>> 1
```

All of this is assuming you will be using this `list` for something other than direct DataFrame indexing of course. (Because obviously this won't work for that!)

Answer (score 1):

You can get integer index from datetimeindex by

```py
import numpy as np
np.where(df.index.isin(df.index))
```

Output:

```bash
(array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.index.get_loc(idx)` is the winner

```
idx = '2016-08-03 16:00:00'
print(df.shape)
%timeit df.index.get_loc(idx)
print(df.index.get_loc(idx))
%timeit np.where(df.index.isin([idx]))
print(np.where(df.index.isin([idx])))
```

output:

```
    (121275, 1)
187 µs ± 1.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
103770
885 µs ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
(array([103770]),)
```